# An example of tensor product

Tags: tensor-products

Let L be field extension of K. Can any one show that Hom($K^n,K^m$)${\otimes}_K$L=Hom($L^n,L^m$).Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that $\hom(K^n,K^m)\cong K^{m\times n}$, by arranging the images of the standard basis vectors in the columns of a matrix.
We can then naturally define a $K$-bilinear map $K^{m\times n}\times L\,\to\,L^{m\times n}$, namely
$$(A,\lambda)\, \mapsto\lambda\cdot A$$
where $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix with coefficients in $K$. This mapping induces a linear $\phi:K^{m\times n}\otimes L\,\to\,L^{m\times n}$, which has an inverse:

Let $E_{ij}$ be the matrix which has $1$ at the $(i,j)$th entry and 0 everywhere else. These form a basis of $L^{m\times n}$ over $L$. It means that any matrix $B\in L^{m\times n}$ can be (uniquely) written in the form
$$B=\sum_{ij}\lambda_{ij}\,E_{ij}\,,\quad \ \lambda_{ij}\in L$$
where anyways, $B=(\lambda_{ij})_{ij}$. Since $\{0,1\}\subseteq K$, we have $E_{ij}\in K^{m\times n}$, and then consider
$$\psi:= \ B\mapsto \sum_{ij}(E_{ij}\otimes \lambda_{ij})\,.$$
Prove that this is indeed the inverse of $\phi$.